# Error when running batch file with default option

Tags: batch

I faced error when running below script in a batch file. The file location of the batch is

"**C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches_Win**\AAADH_Master_Win.bat"

and the file location of the cmd file is in the same subfolder as the batch file :

"**C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches_Win**\CENAS_Detect_Extract.cmd"

From the error dialogue, it couldn't achieve the full directory name : **Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04** !
Appreciate any help to rectify this. Thanks.

```
start "" "%~dp0CENAS_Detect_Extract.cmd" "/d 1 /t 10" "default is 1 after 10 secs"
```

The error when ran the script is as pictured.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try making it like this instead for the batch:

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
start "" "CENAS_Detect_Extract.cmd" "/d 1 /t 10" "default is 1 after 10 secs"
```

@setlocal enableextensions - controls the visibility of environment variables[^] and enables cmd extensions[^].

@cd /d "%~dp0" - Changes the current directory to %~dp0 which is a special batch parameter[^] that expands to the drive and directory that batch file is located in.

%0 expands to the full path and file name of the batch file, adding the ~dp modifier in the middle to make %~dp0 reduces the %0 value to just the drive and path.

[Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/119828/Running-a-bat-file-as-administrator-Correcting-cur)